# ParallelRefProcEnabled Default Number of Threads

Tags: java, garbage-collection

What are default number of threads the JVM assigns when the option    -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled    ? Is there a way we can control the number of threads that do reference processng? If yes, what is the parameter to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ParallelGCThreads` controls the parallelism of all stop-the-world GC phases, which should include parallel reference processing.

Its default is calculated based on your current machine, you can see it via

```
java -XX:+Use????GC -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | grep ParallelGCThreads
```

(fill in the GC you're using, defaults may vary)

Note that GC reference processing is not the same as finalization or `Cleaner` execution, which happens outside GC pauses.

Answer (score 0):

The very first line of this Open JDK Release Note [1] says:

> By default, G1 now determines the optimal number of threads

The Release Note does not say how to change it.
So to answer your question, the default number of threads used is calculated by G1 at runtime.

It also says

> The change improves this phase of the garbage collection pause significantly on machines with more than one thread available for garbage collection.

...although it does not say how it determines the count of available threads.

Link [2] provides more specifics, and refers to this as "dynamic number of thread
sizing" and this is also suggests that the dynamic allocation is sometimes limited to avoid slowdowns in previous implementations:

> Threads are by default automatically limited by the functionality
> introduced with JDK-8043575 to avoid actually being slower than before
> if using too many threads.

[1]  https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8205328
[2]  https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/hotspot-gc-dev/2018-June/022381.html